# How to get focus back when SHBrowseForFolder returns

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, windows-shell

I'm currently using `SHBrowseForFolder()` to open a browse folder window but how do I return focus to my main window when *Cancel* / *OK* is pressed. I read that I should re-enable my main window before the dialog closes but where is that exactly? Any thoughts?

```
void buttonPush(HWND hWnd) {
    EnableWindow(hWnd, FALSE);
    BROWSEINFO bi = { 0 };
    TCHAR szDir[MAX_PATH] = { 0 };
    LPITEMIDLIST pid = NULL;
    LPMALLOC pMalloc = NULL;

    if (SUCCEEDED(SHGetMalloc(&pMalloc)))
    {
        ZeroMemory(&bi,sizeof(bi));
        bi.hwndOwner = NULL;
        bi.pszDisplayName = NULL;
        bi.pidlRoot = NULL;
        bi.ulFlags = BIF_RETURNONLYFSDIRS | BIF_STATUSTEXT | BIF_USENEWUI;
        bi.lpfn = BrowseCallbackProc;

        pidl = SHBrowseForFolder(&bi); 
        if (pidl) 
        { 
            // Folder selected in dialog
            pMalloc->Free(pidl); 
        } 
        pMalloc->Release();
    }
    EnableWindow(hWnd, TRUE);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of enabling and disabling your main window, just set `bi.hwndOwner = hWnd;` Then it will enable and disable automatically.

Answer (score 5):

```
  EnableWindow(hWnd, false);
```

This goes wrong because you are helping too much.  When the dialog closes, there is no window left in your application that can still receive the focus.  Your hWnd is still disabled, it doesn't get enabled until later.  So the Windows window manager is forced to find another window to give the focus to.  That will be the window of another app.  Inevitably your window will disappear behind it.

Delete the EnableWindow() calls.  That is enough, but you can tell the dialog about your window so it won't have to guess at it, useful if your window isn't the active window for some reason:

```
  bi.hwndOwner = hWnd;
```

Comment: @drwbns just curious what led you to the original version instead of the correct version. Did you not understand what `hwndOwner` was for? Or you thought you wanted an ownerless window?